# How to print all the attributes of a zsh parameter?

Tags: zsh

I can give the `-U` attribute to a non-associative array so that it can't contain duplicate elements:

```
% declare -U path
% path=( ~/bin $path )
% path=( ~/bin $path )
% echo $path
```

Here, even though I've added `~/bin` to the array `path` twice, the latter contains only one `~/bin` element.

I'm looking for a way to print all the attributes which can be given to a parameter during an assignment, including this `-U` attribute.

I've looked at the `typeset` command in `man zshbuiltins`, and found this excerpt:

> Except  when  assignments are made with name=value, using +m forces the matching parameters and
>   their attributes to be printed, even inside a function.

So, I've tried executing these commands:

```
% declare -U path
% declare +m 'path'
```

Whose output is:

```
array path
```

While it tells me the type of the parameter (here an array), it doesn't tell me that it has the `-U` attribute.

Is there another command which would print all the attributes of a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ echo ${(t)path}
array-unique-special
```

I'd expect `typeset -p path` (or `declare`; I prefer `typeset` as it's more portable) to give that information. It doesn't though in current versions which seems like a bug to me (**Edit**: [now fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/a75b47973d65b92c33078e06ec080a945e076943)).

You can also use:

```
typeset -U +
```

To list the variables with the `unique` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing the bug. `declare -p path` prints `typeset -a path=(...)`, but it doesn't report that `path` is a tied array (created with the `-T` option). Shouldn't it print `typeset -a -T PATH=... path=(...)`? OTOH, `echo ${(t)path}` prints `array-special`. I suppose `special` means the array is tied to `PATH`. Also, `declare -T` doesn't print anything, while I have 10 tied arrays (`cdpath`, `fignore`, ...). Is it supposed to ignore the tied arrays created automatically by the shell?

Comment: Ah, `typeset -a -T PATH=... path=(...)` is not a valid command. It should have been `typeset -T PATH path`. So `typeset -p` must choose between reporting that the array is tied, or giving its value. It can't do both at the same time...

Comment: No _special_ is because `$PATH` is special to the shell. After `typeset -T A a`, I see a `tag_local` which is wrong as `tag_local` refers to a function (not variable) property. It should show _tied_ there.

Comment: "I prefer typeset as it's more portable": would you mind elaborating on that? (I noted that both `typeset` and `declare` can be used with both bash and zsh.)

Comment: @Carl, `typeset` was introduced by ksh circa 1983, there's no good reason why bash chose to name the same thing `declare`.